# Unknown Provider | Angular Bootstrap Colorpicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, color-picker

I'm encountering this error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: colorpicker.moduleProvider <- colorpicker.module
```

using this module: [Angular Bootstrap Colorpicker](https://github.com/buberdds/angular-bootstrap-colorpicker)

and this installation:

**bootstrap-colorpicker-module.js**

```
angular.module('colorpicker.module', [])
.factory('Helper', function () {
  return {...
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('myApp', [
'ngRoute',
'animations',
'myApp.filters',
'myApp.services',
'myApp.directives',
'myApp.controllers',
'colorpicker.module']).config...
```

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
        .controller('Login', ['$scope', 'colorpicker.module', function($scope, colorpicker) {...
```

**index.html**

```
<div ng-view></div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/twitter-bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.0-beta.3/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>
    <script src="js/animations.js"></script>
    <script src='js/bootstrap-colorpicker-module.js'></script>
</body>
```

If I need to provide more information, I will. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild. Leaving the colorpicker out of the controller injection completely solves the issue. I suppose because it's included in the app's global module?

Thanks everyone for your help!

**controllers.js**

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('Login', ['$scope', function($scope) {...
```

Comment: You could also use a simpler colorpicker: https://github.com/twler/angular-web-colorpicker

Answer (score 2):

Regarding this http://codepen.io/clouddueling/pen/tyKGL you don't have to inject olorpicker.module into controller just into module so your controller should looke like

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['colorpicker.module'])
        .controller('Login', ['$scope', function($scope) {...
```

Comment: This helped the most out of the other answers. Thanks so much, sylwester!

Answer (score 2):

please remove 'colorpicker.module' from the 'myApp.controllers' controller, If it's not work please try to use:

https://github.com/Jimdo/angular-spectrum-colorpicker

angular-spectrum-colorpicker is fully working plugin and you will get full documentation for help.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to be missing the colorpicker.module in the passed arguments in your controller

```
('myApp.controllers', [])
        .controller('Login', ['$scope', 'colorpicker.module', function($scope, colorpicker.module) {...
```

Comment: Angular returns an "expected , instead found ." error on the dot in colorpicker.module. Thanks though!